# df differs from du a lot, nfsd service seems matter

Tags: centos7, xfs, df, du

I know there have been a lot of discussion on the df/du discrepancy topic. But here I’d post a special issue and ask for some hints.
here is the detail( with a hardware raid5 with 6 sas disks)

1. system info of nfs server/client:
   [root@ndio06 ~]# cat /etc/*release*|grep CentOS
   CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
   NAME="CentOS Linux"
   PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
   CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
   CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
   [root@ndio06 ~]# uname -a
   Linux ndio06 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
   [root@ndio06 ~]# rpm -qa|grep nfs-util
   nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.61.el7.x86_64

The nfs server normally is under heavy load serving 48 busy nodes with lots of processes, io operation.

2. df/du not aligned, and the gap is huge:
   [root@ndio06 ~]# df -hl /CAE;du -sh /CAE
   Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   /dev/sdb1       5.0T  3.6T  1.4T  73% /CAE
   736G    /CAE
3. no “deleted but in use” files on nfs server or 40+ clients:
   [root@pbs ~]# for node in `pestat|grep ndpam02|awk {'print $1'}|grep -v io`; do echo --$node--;ssh $node lsof +D /CAE|grep -i "deleted" ;done
   --nd065--
   --nd066--
   --nd067--
   ..........
4. mount options on the clients:

ndio06-ib:/CAE on /CAE type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,soft,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.72,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.161)

5. what has been observed:
   — an xfs_repair after unmount would fix the issue, however it would come up again after some weeks. Unfortunately I did not capture the information during the repair to see it there are any physical issues with the raid/disks.

- a restart of nfsd service would fix it and df would give right percentage after a few tries (Each tries would get a lower percentage used%) or wait for a few minutes. Again the is just a temp fix and the issue would come up few days or weeks later.
- The nfs service is still responsive unless df reports 100% usage. The nfsd thread number is set to 8.

Anybody can kindly give a light on this issue? Can provide more info if needed.

Thanks.